# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. JQuery validation in ASP.NET Web Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I'm trying to validate an ASP.NET web form using jQuery validation

In Site.Master I include these scripts

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

In Modify.aspx, I include a custom script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= Form.ClientID%>').validate({
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).removeClass('has-error');
            }
        });
    }(jQuery));
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to add or remove css class for input that are validated.

Then I got an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Can anyone help me to resolve the problem? Perhaps the script isn't correct too, please help me to modify it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: make sure client id not empty / null, var clientId = '#<%= Form.ClientID%>'; console.log(clientId);

Comment: yes it's not null. It returns $('form1').validate

Comment: Why are you loading development AND minified versions of all your libraries? Why are you using such an ancient version of jQuery?

Comment: Your browser's developer tools should tell you what undefined thing is not a function. You need to narrow your problem down.

Comment: how about element inside highlight and unhighlight, var $element = $(element); console.log($element);

Comment: Include only minified versions of jQuery and jQuery validations

Comment: It says Uncaught TypeError right below the line $('#form1').validate({

Comment: reading the comment, it could be the jquery symbol it self, $, that null

Comment: I exclude jquery-1.4.4.js and jquery.validate.js but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I don't think jquery validate will work with such an old version of jquery - try updating your library

Answer (score 4):

I agree with others who say you should not be using retired libraries and mixing full and minified versions of scripts in your import code.The following code snippet below should give you a head start.A bootstrap css reference has been added for cosmetics.

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-validate.min.js"></script>
<link href="Scripts/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#form1').validate({
            onKeyup: true,
            eachValidField: function () {

                $(this).closest('div').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            },
            eachInvalidField: function () {

                $(this).closest('div').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            }
    });
    });
```

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" class="test">
<div class="control-group input-append">
<input type="text" data-required="true"/>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
```